# Direct X 11 : Drawing A Simple Colored Rectangle On Screen

Tags: c++, winapi, rendering, directx-11

Now I know this question has been asked countless times(Same problem but different code) and I know this is difficult to debug but this is an homework assignment due 1 week from now and I have been struggling for 4 days with this now(which means I have only 3 days remaining including today) submission on Monday or Tuesday morning by max so please help me out :(.

All I want is to draw an simple colored square on the screen in direct x 11(my supported feature level is 9_1). Now what I have done so far

1)Checked every HRESULT returned by litraly every function. Even if one fails the application terminates.
All have Passed!!!

2)Created the device & shaders in debug mode. No errors Anywhere!!

U can see why I am frustrated. The Code I am about to post here can be copied & pasted directly and ran with no problems(Compiled in Visual Studio 2017 but that's no bige).

6 Files have to be created

```
1)DirectX.h
2)DirectX.cpp
3)Scene.h
4)Scene.cpp
5)VShader.hlsl
6)PShader.hlsl
```

And Now the code

DirectX.h

```
#ifndef DIRECTX_H
#define DIRECTX_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <d3d11.h>

class D3D11Device
{
 private:
 D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;
 ID3D11Device* device;
 ID3D11DeviceContext* context;
 IDXGISwapChain* swapChain;

 private:
 ID3D11RenderTargetView* target;
 ID3D11DepthStencilView* buffer;
 ID3D11RasterizerState*  rState;

 private:
 int errors;
 D3D11Device(HWND, int, int);


 public:
 static D3D11Device* Create(HWND, int, int);
 void bindTargets();
 int resize(int, int);
 ID3D11Device* getDevice();
 ID3D11DeviceContext* getContext();
 void clear(float,float,float,float);
 void present();
 ~D3D11Device();
};

#endif DIRECTX_H
```

DirectX.cpp

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "DirectX.h"

    D3D11Device::D3D11Device(HWND window,int w,int h)
    {
     errors = 0;
     device = nullptr;
     context = nullptr;
     swapChain = nullptr;
     rState = nullptr;
     target = nullptr;
     buffer = nullptr;
     D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL level = {};

     D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
           D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
        };


     //CREATE DEVICE AND CONTEXT
     HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr,D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,0,D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG
                                   ,levels,ARRAYSIZE(levels),D3D11_SDK_VERSION
                                   ,&device,&level,&context);
     if (FAILED(hr))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Device And Context", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }






     //CREATE SWAP CHAIN
     DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc = {};

     desc.Windowed = TRUE;
     desc.OutputWindow = window;
     desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
     desc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

     desc.BufferCount = 2;
     desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
     desc.BufferDesc.Width = w;
     desc.BufferDesc.Height = h;
     desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

     desc.SampleDesc.Count=1;
     desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;


     IDXGIDevice* dxgidevice =nullptr;
     IDXGIAdapter* adapter=nullptr;
     IDXGIFactory* factory=nullptr;
     if (FAILED(device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&dxgidevice)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Get DXGI Device", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     if (FAILED(dxgidevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&adapter)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Get DXGI Adapter", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     if (FAILED(adapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Get DXGI Factory", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     if (FAILED(factory->CreateSwapChain(device, &desc, &swapChain)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Swap Chain", L"Failed Swap Chain", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     dxgidevice->Release();
     adapter->Release();
     factory->Release();






     //CREATING RENDER TARGET AND DEPTH&STENCIL BUFFER
     ID3D11Texture2D* texture;

     if (FAILED(swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&texture)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Aquire Back Buffer", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     if (FAILED(device->CreateRenderTargetView(texture, NULL, &target)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Render Target", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     texture->Release();


     depthStencilDesc = {};

     depthStencilDesc.Width = w;
     depthStencilDesc.Height = h;
     depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
     depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;

     depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
     depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
     depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;

     depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
     depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
     depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
     depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

     if (FAILED(device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, NULL, &texture)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create DepthStencil Texture", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     if (FAILED(device->CreateDepthStencilView(texture, 0, &buffer)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create DepthStencil Buffer", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     texture->Release();





     //SET RASTERIZER STATE
     D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rDesc = {};
     rDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
     rDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
     rDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
     rDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
     if (FAILED(device->CreateRasterizerState(&rDesc, &rState)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Rasterizer State", L"Failed Rasterizer State", MB_OK);
      errors = 1;
      return;
     }
     context->RSSetState(rState);





     //SET VIEW PORT
     D3D11_VIEWPORT viewPort = {};
     viewPort.TopLeftX=0;
     viewPort.TopLeftY=0;
     viewPort.Width =(float)w;
     viewPort.Height =(float)h;
     viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
     viewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
     context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewPort);
    }

    D3D11Device* D3D11Device::Create(HWND parent,int w,int h)
    {
     D3D11Device* directx = new D3D11Device(parent,w,h);
     if (directx->errors == 1)
     {
      delete directx;
      directx = nullptr;
     }
     return directx;
    }

    int D3D11Device::resize(int width,int height)
    {
     target->Release();
     buffer->Release();
     target = nullptr;
     buffer = nullptr;

     context->OMSetRenderTargets(0, nullptr, nullptr);
     context->Flush();
     if (FAILED(swapChain->ResizeBuffers(2, width, height, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Resize Buffers", L"Failed Resize", MB_OK);
      return -1;
     }


     ID3D11Texture2D* texture=nullptr;

     if (FAILED(swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&texture)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Aquire Back Buffer", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      return -1;
     }
     if (FAILED(device->CreateRenderTargetView(texture, NULL, &target)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Render Target", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      return -1;
     }
     texture->Release();
     texture = nullptr;



     depthStencilDesc.Width = width;
     depthStencilDesc.Height = height;
     if (FAILED(device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, NULL, &texture)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create DepthStencil Texture", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      return -1;
     }
     if (FAILED(device->CreateDepthStencilView(texture, 0, &buffer)))
     {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create DepthStencil Buffer", L"Failed D3D Init", MB_OK);
      return -1;
     }
     texture->Release();
     texture = nullptr;


     D3D11_VIEWPORT viewPort = {};
     viewPort.TopLeftX = 0;
     viewPort.TopLeftY = 0;
     viewPort.Width =(float)width;
     viewPort.Height =(float)height;
     viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
     viewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
     context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewPort);

     return 1;
    }

    ID3D11Device* D3D11Device::getDevice() { return device; }
    ID3D11DeviceContext* D3D11Device::getContext() { return context; }

    void D3D11Device::bindTargets() { context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &target, buffer); }
    void D3D11Device::clear(float r, float g, float b, float a)
    {
     float color[4] = { r,g,b,a };
     context->ClearRenderTargetView(target, color);
 context->ClearDepthStencilView(buffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH |D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL,0, 0);
    }
    void D3D11Device::present() { swapChain->Present(0,0); }

    D3D11Device::~D3D11Device()
    {
     if (rState != nullptr) { rState->Release(); }
     if (target != nullptr) { target->Release(); }
     if (buffer != nullptr) { buffer->Release(); }

     if (swapChain != nullptr)
     {
      swapChain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE,NULL);
      swapChain->Release();
     }
     if (device != nullptr) { device->Release(); }
     if (context != nullptr) { context->Release(); }
    }
```

Scene.h

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DirectX.h"
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

class Scene;

class Window
{
 private:
 HWND window;
 Scene* scene;
 int errors;

 private:
 Window(HINSTANCE, int, int, int, int);
 static LRESULT CALLBACK winProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

 public:
 static Window* Create(HINSTANCE, int, int, int, int);
 void display(int);
 Scene* getScene();
 ~Window();
};

struct ShaderInfo
{
 LPCWSTR vFile;
 LPCSTR  vEntry;
 LPCSTR  vVersion;

 LPCWSTR pFile;
 LPCSTR  pEntry;
 LPCSTR  pVersion;
 ID3DInclude* pIncludes;
};

class Include : public ID3DInclude
{
 private:
 ID3DBlob* blob;

 public:
 HRESULT _stdcall Open(D3D_INCLUDE_TYPE, LPCSTR, LPCVOID, LPCVOID*, UINT*);
 HRESULT _stdcall Close(LPCVOID);
};

class RasterShader
{
 private:
 int errors;
 ID3D11InputLayout* inputLayout;
 ID3D11VertexShader* vShader;
 ID3D11PixelShader*  pShader;

 private:
 RasterShader(ID3D11Device*,ShaderInfo*);
 HRESULT Compile(LPCWSTR,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,ID3DInclude*,ID3DBlob**);

 public:
 static RasterShader* Create(ID3D11Device*,ShaderInfo*);
 void render(ID3D11DeviceContext*);
 ~RasterShader();
};

class QuadGeometry
{
 private:
 int errors;
 ID3D11Buffer* vertexBuffer;
 ID3D11Buffer* colorBuffer;
 ID3D11Buffer* indexBuffer;

 private:
 QuadGeometry(ID3D11Device*);
 HRESULT createBuffer(ID3D11Device* device,UINT,D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA*,int,ID3D11Buffer**);

 public:
 static QuadGeometry* Create(ID3D11Device*);
 void render(ID3D11DeviceContext*);
 ~QuadGeometry();
};

class Scene
{
 private:
 int errors;
 D3D11Device* directx;
 RasterShader* shader;
 QuadGeometry* geometry;

 private:
 Scene(HWND,int,int);

 public:
 static Scene* Create(HWND,int,int);
 void render();
 int resize(int, int);
 ~Scene();
};

#endif SCENE_H
```

Scene.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Scene.h"

Window::Window(HINSTANCE app, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
 errors = 0;

 WNDCLASSEX wClass = {};
 wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
 wClass.hInstance = app;
 wClass.lpszClassName = L"Window";
 wClass.lpfnWndProc = winProc;
 if (!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
 {
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Register Window Class", L"Window Class", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }

 window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"Window", L"Direct X", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
                        ,x, y, w, h
                        ,NULL, 0, app, this);
 if(!window)
 {
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Window", L"Window", MB_OK);
  errors = 1; 
 }
}

LRESULT Window::winProc(HWND parent, UINT msg, WPARAM high, LPARAM low)
{
 if (msg == WM_CREATE)
 {
  LPCREATESTRUCT create = (LPCREATESTRUCT)(low);
  Window* thisClass = (Window*)create->lpCreateParams;

  RECT rect = {};
  GetWindowRect(parent, &rect);
  thisClass->scene = Scene::Create(parent, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
  if (thisClass->scene == nullptr) { return -1; }

  SetWindowLongPtr(parent, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONGLONG)thisClass);
  return 1;
 }
 else if (msg == WM_SIZE)
 {
  Window* window = (Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(parent, GWLP_USERDATA);
  int newWidth = (int)LOWORD(low);
  int newHeight = (int)HIWORD(low);
  return window->scene->resize(newWidth,newHeight);
 }
 else if (msg == WM_CLOSE)
 {
  DestroyWindow(parent);
  return 1;
 }
 else if (msg == WM_DESTROY)
 {
  PostQuitMessage(0);
  return 1;
 }
 return DefWindowProc(parent, msg, high, low);
}

Window* Window::Create(HINSTANCE app, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
 Window* window = new Window(app, x, y, w, h);
 if (window->errors == 1)
 {
  delete window;
  window = nullptr;
 }
 return window;
}

void Window::display(int code) { ShowWindow(window, code); }
Scene* Window::getScene() { return scene; }
Window::~Window()
{
 if (scene != nullptr) { delete scene; }
 UnregisterClass(L"Window", GetModuleHandle(NULL));
}













HRESULT Include::Open
(
    D3D_INCLUDE_TYPE IncludeType,
    LPCSTR           pFileName,
    LPCVOID          pParentData,
    LPCVOID          *ppData,
    UINT             *pBytes
)
{
 CString D(pFileName);
 if (FAILED(D3DReadFileToBlob(D.GetBuffer(), &blob)))
 {
  CString fileName(pFileName);
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Load File", fileName.GetBuffer(), MB_OK);
  fileName.ReleaseBuffer();
  return D3D10_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
 }
 D.ReleaseBuffer();

 (*ppData) = blob->GetBufferPointer();
 (*pBytes) = blob->GetBufferSize();

 return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Include::Close(LPCVOID data) 
{
 blob->Release();
 return S_OK; 
}


RasterShader::RasterShader(ID3D11Device* device,ShaderInfo* info)
{
 ID3DBlob* compiledCode=nullptr;
 inputLayout = nullptr;
 vShader = nullptr;
 pShader = nullptr;
 errors = 0;

 if (FAILED(Compile(info->vFile,info->vEntry,info->vVersion,nullptr,&compiledCode)))
 {
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }
 if (FAILED(device->CreateVertexShader(compiledCode->GetBufferPointer(), compiledCode->GetBufferSize(),nullptr, &vShader)))
 {
  compiledCode->Release();
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Vertex Shader", L"Failed Vertex Shader", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }

 D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC desc[] =
 {
   {"POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
  ,{"COLOR",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,1,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0}
 };
 if (FAILED(device->CreateInputLayout(desc,2,compiledCode->GetBufferPointer(),compiledCode->GetBufferSize(),&inputLayout)))
 {
  compiledCode->Release();
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Input Layout", L"Failed Input Layout", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }
 compiledCode->Release();
 compiledCode = nullptr;


 if (FAILED(Compile(info->pFile, info->pEntry, info->pVersion,info->pIncludes,&compiledCode)))
 {
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }
 if (FAILED(device->CreatePixelShader(compiledCode->GetBufferPointer(), compiledCode->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &pShader)))
 {
  compiledCode->Release();
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Pixel Shader", L"Failed Pixel Shader", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }
 compiledCode->Release();
 compiledCode = nullptr;
}

HRESULT RasterShader::Compile(LPCWSTR fileName,LPCSTR entry,LPCSTR version,ID3DInclude* include,ID3DBlob** code)
{
 ID3DBlob* errors=nullptr;
 HRESULT hr = D3DCompileFromFile(fileName,nullptr,include
                                ,entry,version
                                ,D3DCOMPILE_WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS,0,code,&errors);
 if (FAILED(hr))
 {
  if (errors!=nullptr)
  {
   CString data((char*)errors->GetBufferPointer());
   MessageBox(NULL, data.GetBuffer(),fileName, MB_OK);

   data.ReleaseBuffer();
   errors->Release();
  }
 }
 return hr;
}

RasterShader * RasterShader::Create(ID3D11Device* device,ShaderInfo* info)
{
 RasterShader* shader = new RasterShader(device,info);
 if (shader->errors == 1)
 {
  delete shader;
  shader = nullptr;
 }
 return shader;
}

void RasterShader::render(ID3D11DeviceContext* context)
{
 context->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout);
 context->VSSetShader(vShader, nullptr, 0);
 context->PSSetShader(pShader, nullptr, 0);
}

RasterShader::~RasterShader()
{
 if (inputLayout != nullptr) { inputLayout->Release(); }
 if (vShader != nullptr) { vShader->Release(); }
 if (pShader != nullptr) { pShader->Release(); }
}













QuadGeometry::QuadGeometry(ID3D11Device* device)
{
 errors = 0;
 vertexBuffer = nullptr;
 colorBuffer = nullptr;
 indexBuffer = nullptr;
 D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA Data = {};


 DirectX::XMFLOAT2 verts[]=
 {
   DirectX::XMFLOAT2(0.5f,0.5f)
  ,DirectX::XMFLOAT2(-0.5f,0.5f)
  ,DirectX::XMFLOAT2(-0.5f,-0.5f)
  ,DirectX::XMFLOAT2(0.5f,-0.5f)
 };
 Data.pSysMem = verts;
 Data.SysMemPitch = 0;
 Data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
 if(FAILED(createBuffer(device, D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER,&Data,sizeof(DirectX::XMFLOAT2) * 4,&vertexBuffer)))
 {
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Vertex Buffer", L"Failed Vertex Buffer", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }

 DirectX::XMFLOAT3 colors[] =
 {
   DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1,0,0)
  ,DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0,1,0)
  ,DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1,0,1)
  ,DirectX::XMFLOAT3(1,1,0)
 };
 Data.pSysMem = colors;
 Data.SysMemPitch = 0;
 Data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
 if (FAILED(createBuffer(device, D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER,&Data, sizeof(DirectX::XMFLOAT3) * 4, &colorBuffer)))
 {
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Color Buffer", L"Failed Color Buffer", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }

 UINT indices[]=
 {
   0,1,2
  ,0,2,3
 };
 Data.pSysMem = indices;
 Data.SysMemPitch = 0;
 Data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
 if (FAILED(createBuffer(device, D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER, &Data, sizeof(UINT) * 6, &indexBuffer)))
 {
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed To Create Index Buffer", L"Failed Index Buffer", MB_OK);
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }
}

HRESULT QuadGeometry::createBuffer(ID3D11Device* device,UINT bind,D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA* data,int byteSize,ID3D11Buffer** buffer)
{
 D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc = {};
 desc.BindFlags = bind;
 desc.ByteWidth = byteSize;
 desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
 desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
 desc.MiscFlags = 0;
 desc.StructureByteStride = 0;

 return device->CreateBuffer(&desc,data,buffer);
}

QuadGeometry * QuadGeometry::Create(ID3D11Device* device)
{
 QuadGeometry* geom = new QuadGeometry(device);
 if (geom->errors == 1)
 {
  delete geom;
  geom = nullptr;
 }
 return geom;
}

void QuadGeometry::render(ID3D11DeviceContext* context)
{
 UINT strides[] = { sizeof(DirectX::XMFLOAT2),sizeof(DirectX::XMFLOAT3)};
 UINT offsets[] = { 0,0 };
 ID3D11Buffer* buffers[] = {vertexBuffer,colorBuffer};

 context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 2, buffers, strides, offsets);
 context->IASetIndexBuffer(indexBuffer,DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
 context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

 context->DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);
}

QuadGeometry::~QuadGeometry()
{
 if (vertexBuffer != nullptr) { vertexBuffer->Release(); }
 if (colorBuffer != nullptr) { colorBuffer->Release(); }
 if (indexBuffer != nullptr) { indexBuffer->Release(); }
}











Scene::Scene(HWND window, int w, int h)
{
 errors = 0;
 directx = nullptr;
 shader = nullptr;
 geometry = nullptr;

 directx = D3D11Device::Create(window, w, h);
 if (directx == nullptr)
 {
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }

 ShaderInfo info = {};
 info.vFile = L"VShader.hlsl";
 info.vEntry = "VShader";
 info.vVersion = "vs_4_0_level_9_1";
 info.pFile = L"PShader.hlsl";
 info.pEntry = "PShader";
 info.pVersion = "ps_4_0_level_9_1";
 info.pIncludes = (ID3DInclude*)new Include();
 shader = RasterShader::Create(directx->getDevice(), &info);
 if (shader == nullptr)
 {
  errors = 1;
  return;
 }

 geometry = QuadGeometry::Create(directx->getDevice());
 if (geometry == nullptr){errors = 1;}
}

Scene * Scene::Create(HWND window, int w, int h)
{
 Scene* scene = new Scene(window, w, h);
 if (scene->errors == 1)
 {
  delete scene;
  scene = nullptr;
 }
 return scene;
}

void Scene::render()
{
 directx->clear(0, 0, 0.5f, 0);

 directx->bindTargets();
 shader->render(directx->getContext());
 geometry->render(directx->getContext());

 directx->present();
}

int Scene::resize(int w, int h) { return directx->resize(w, h); }

Scene::~Scene()
{
 if (shader != nullptr) { delete shader; }
 if (geometry != nullptr) { delete geometry; }
 if (directx != nullptr) { delete directx; }
}
```

VShader.hlsl

```
struct VIn
{
 float2 position: POSITION;
 float3 color   : COLOR;
};

struct VOut
{
 float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
 float3 clr :     COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(in VIn input)
{
 VOut output;

 output.pos = float4(input.position.x,input.position.y,0,1.0f);
 output.clr = input.color;

 return output;
}
```

PShader.hlsl

```
# include "VShader.hlsl"

float4 PShader(in VOut input) : SV_TARGET
{
  return float4(1,0,1,0);
}
```

Like I said this code can be copied & pasted with no issues. Library files requires are d3d11.lib & d3dcompiler.lib

I don't know what the issue is or where I went wrong but hopefully if anyone does manage to find the issue I hope this code can help someone out there get started with direct x 11 :).

All I get is an blue screen that can toogle between fullscreen and windowed(half the output expected). but the quad is not there.

Please help someone . Thank you.

Comment: I don't know much about DirectX, but it seems weird that your pixel shader completely ignores its input parameter and just produces pixels with alpha value 0.

Comment: True. But right now I just wanted to test if I can see an purple colored quad(1,0,1,0)[or some color] on the screen to see if my parameters were passed correctly[i.e the vertices]. Didn't work out :(.

Comment: I see you set up a depth stencil. Did you ever clear it?

Comment: Ohh!! just a sec ill be back in 5 minutes

Comment: @RVISHAL Alpha value 0 would mean nothing is rendered if alpha testing is enabled.

Comment: Yup cleared the depth & stencil buffer and I don't have alpha blending enabled.Tried alpha of both 1& 0 no progress. Also I have culling disabled so my winding rule(in my case counter clock wise) dosent matter so I hope that helps

Comment: https://renderdoc.org/ try debugging with renderdoc. you might see why/where it fails, its a useful tool to know how to use

Comment: Well just downloaded render doc. I tried diagnosis and all variables came out empty. Maybe nothing is getting passed to the vertex shader for some reason

Comment: @RVISHAL In render doc, capture a frame, on the left panel find your draw call, i.e. DrawIndexed(6). “Pipeline state” tab, verify the vertex/index buffer is OK, and input layout.
You can click on the “Mesh view”, it will show you your input data on “VS In” tab, also the geometry after your vertex shader, “VS Out” tab.

Comment: Yeah about that it works now ._.?!?. I just created a new project and pasted all my files in there exactly unchanged and now everything works. I blame Visual Studio

Comment: You should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and the ``PrimitiveBatch`` class.

Comment: The DirectX 11 framework is very clear. Based on the questions of the previous reviewers, I will not repeat them. There is a problem in the `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC desc[]`, the `COLOR` InputSlot is 0, and the `AlignedByteOffset` should be 8.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why it doesn’t work, but here’re some problems I see there.

1. In the PS, you’re returning colors with alpha = 0. Apparently, you don’t setup alpha blending, and the default blend state has alpha blending disabled, but still, for test purposes try output alpha = 1.0.
2. You’re creating index buffer with 32-bit indices, `UINT` is 32-bit integers. Yet you’re telling D3D the index buffer contains 16-bit indices, `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT`.

Couple general notes about the code.

You’re compiling shader sources at runtime. Don’t. Compile them offline for the lowest feature level you support (9.1?), and in runtime, load shaders from DXBC file. Compiling shaders causes lots of unnecessary complexity in your code, and it also takes time. If you’re using VC++, include hlsl files into the project, right click, Properties, “HLSL Compiler / General” set up shader type and model, “HLSL Compiler / Output Files” set `$(OutDir)%(Filename).cso` in the “Object File Name”. Then in runtime, read these two .cso files from disk, and call `ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader` / `CreatePixelShader`.

You’re creating 2 vertex buffers for positions and colors. One is enough. People usually use multiple vertex buffers when they update some vertex attributes but not others. When everything is immutable like in your case, it’s simpler, and more efficient, to use a single buffer. Define a structure containing both fields, and change input layout accordingly.

You’re creating a device with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG but apparently you don’t read debug output. Launch your app with debugger, and read the output window in visual studio. With that flag, very often, the runtime just prints what’s wrong with your resources / shaders / states / whatever else is involved.

Comment: The debug window doesn't contain any directx related queries only loading pdb and dll files stuff like that. Yes I do use 2 buffers for both. Part of the learning curve but only after trying interleaving both of them(still no luck). Also I loaded pre compiled (by visual studio itself)cso files into my shaders. Still no luck

Comment: Also DXGI_FORMAT for my indices like R32_UINT or R8_UINT give me debug erros at runtime

Comment: Right now I am not focusing on optimizations just trying out every way  we can do stuff but thanks for the tips though. Yes my feature level is 9_1

Comment: @RVISHAL The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-iasetindexbuffer says DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT is valid for index buffers.
If it fails in runtime, this means you have other issues. Read what’s written in the debug output.

Comment: R8_UINT is indeed invalid.

Comment: I used R32_UINT and I got this error.     D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer: The Format (0x2a, R32_UINT) is not valid for usage as an IAIndexBuffer Format. [ STATE_SETTING ERROR #242: DEVICE_IASETINDEXBUFFER_FORMAT_INVALID]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer: CreateResource: 32-bit indices are not supported. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #1048609: CREATERESOURCE_NO_DWORD_INDEX_BUFFER]

Comment: I think that's because I have a feature level of 9_1 but that's okay. i don't need 32 bit indices anyway

Comment: @RVISHAL 32-bit index buffers require feature level 9.3 or above. Here’s the table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/format-support-for-direct3d-feature-level-9-1-hardware row R32_UINT column “Input Assembler Index Buffer”.
Either increase feature level to at least 9.3, or switch to 16-bit index buffers.
If you’ll do the latter, `#include <stdint.h>` and use uint16_t data type for them.

Comment: My device supports only feature level 9_1 and I did as you asked changed my indices to uint16_t. no success

Comment: @RVISHAL Use renderdoc then, see the mesh that you're sending to GPU. Also the mesh after your vertex shader.